# Extracting audio from a video from ".m3u8" URL

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract audio from a video from ".m3u8" URL. It works with this command which is stated below but I could not find how can I do that with a C# wrapper library, like Xabe.FFmpeg, FFMPEGCore. Does anybody know how to do that?

PS: I am using .net core

`ffmpeg -i "https://blablabla/playlist.m3u8" -acodec mp3 -ab 128k test.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I used "Xabe.FFmpeg" library.
You can see the code below.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static string link = "yourlink/playlist.m3u8";

        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mediaInfo = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(link);
            var conversion = await FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.ExtractAudio(mediaInfo.Path, "test.mp3");
            conversion.OnProgress += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"[{args.Duration}/{args.TotalLength}][{args.Percent}%]");
            };

            await conversion.SetAudioBitrate(128000).SetOutputFormat(Format.mp3).Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```